# Open a pdf made with JasperReports through a Vaadin component

Tags: jasper-reports, vaadin

This is the first time that I'm trying to open a pdf made with *iReport* through a *Vaadin* component. I saw on many forum but I can't understand.

Now I will try to explain my problem:

1. I created file (.jasper) with *iReport*
2. I want to open this file when i click on *Vaadin* button

Do you have something that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

update:

Are your generated pdf in pdf or stream?
Firefox/Chrome:
This browsers has own "application/pdf" viewers

Internet Explorer:
for view PDF on IE I'm use Adobe Acrobat Reader.
Adobe Acrobat Reader install plugin for browser.
This plugin detect application/pdf content and show own viewer in Internet Explorer.

This is sample for make this in Vaadin:

```
private void viewDocument() 
{
    final String retrievalName = "222.pdf"; 

    Window window = new Window();
    window.setCaption("View PDF");
    window.getContent().setSizeFull();

    final StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(new StreamResource.StreamSource()
    {
        public InputStream getStream()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] DocContent = null;
                DocContent = getFileBytes("C:\\Temp\\222.pdf");
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(DocContent);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }, retrievalName, getMainWindow().getApplication());

    Embedded c = new Embedded("", resource);
    c.setSizeFull();
    resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
    c.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
    window.addComponent(c);

    window.setModal(true);
    window.setWidth("90%");
    window.setHeight("90%");

    getMainWindow().addWindow(window);
}

/**
 * getFileBytes
 * 
 * @author NBochkarev
 * 
 * @param fileOut
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static byte[] getFileBytes(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
    InputStream ios = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ios = new FileInputStream(new java.io.File(fileName));
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1)
            ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (ous != null)
                ous.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // swallow, since not that important
        }
        try
        {
            if (ios != null)
                ios.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // swallow, since not that important
        }
    }
    return ous.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdfViewer Component at https://vaadin.com/directory/component/pdf-viewer

```
Resource resource=null;
                
String reportPath = "D:";dbservice.getLoggedDistrict().getDistrictId();
resource= new ClassPathResource("report/list.jrxml");
InputStream employeeReportStream = resource.getInputStream();
                JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(employeeReportStream);
                JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(employees);
                //Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                //parameters.put("Parameter1", "Sabaton");
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null,jrBeanCollectionDataSource);
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, reportPath+"//"+user+"report.pdf");
                File a = new File(reportPath+"//"+user+"report.pdf");
                resourcerange = new StreamResource("Report.pdf", () -> createResource(a));
                pdfViewerrange = new PdfViewer();
                pdfViewerrange.setSrc(resourcerange);
                hl4.setSizeFull();
                hl4.add(pdfViewerrange);
```